# SimpleBlobDetector Blob Count

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

How can you determine the number of blobs found using SimpleBlobDetector in Python 2.7? I have sample code finding and marking the blobs in my image but also need to know how many blobs matched my parameters.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Standard imports
import cv2
import numpy as np;
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Read image
im = cv2.imread("blob.jpg")

# Setup SimpleBlobDetector parameters.
params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()

# Change thresholds
params.minThreshold = 10
params.maxThreshold = 200

# Filter by Area.
params.filterByArea = True
params.minArea = 15

# Filter by Circularity
params.filterByCircularity = True
params.minCircularity = 0.1

# Filter by Convexity
params.filterByConvexity = True
params.minConvexity = 0.87

# Filter by Inertia
params.filterByInertia = True
params.minInertiaRatio = 0.01

# Create a detector with the parameters
detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector(params)

# Detect blobs.
keypoints = detector.detect(im)

# Draw detected blobs as red circles.
# cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS ensures
# the size of the circle corresponds to the size of blob

im_with_keypoints = cv2.drawKeypoints(im, keypoints, np.array([]), (255,0,0), cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS

titles = ['Blobs Detected']
images = [im_with_keypoints]


for i in xrange(1):    
    plt.subplot(1,1,i+1), plt.imshow(images[i],'gray')
    plt.title(titles[i])
    plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])  # to hide tick values on X and Y axis    
plt.show()
```

Comment: Show some code demonstrating what you have tried so far. That will encourage others to help.

Comment: Each keypoint is a blob. Just count the keypoints.

Answer (score 1):

You just need

```
nblobs = len(keypoints)
```